# How to disable "delete" when the table section is 0 on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with two sections, and I added a edit button. If I press the edit button, I can delete the item on the UITableView, but I wanna to check the if the section is 0, the delete button will not display, how can I handle it for that purpose? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Implement the `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` method of the table view delegate in your view controller to check for the section. This and other edit methods control both edit and delete capabilities:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```